# Disable cursor change while inside tracking area in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow, nscursor

I'm trying to change cursor while the cursor is inside a view. The problem is that the cursor resets to its default automatically sometimes(for example when a notification popup shows up.)

```
class DrawingView : NSView{

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        
        // Drawing code here.
    }

   override func updateTrackingAreas() {
        let area = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.frame, options: [.cursorUpdate,.activeAlways,.inVisibleRect], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        self.addTrackingArea(area)
    }

    override func cursorUpdate(with event: NSEvent) {
        NSCursor.crosshair.set()
        NSApp.keyWindow?.disableCursorRects()
    }
        
}
```

To my knowledge `NSWindow`'s `disableCursorRects()` is supposed to stop the cursor from changing due to other processes. Maybe I'm using it wrong?

Comment: You change the cursor image for your view in an override of the NSResponder method cursorUpdate:. To receive this message, you must create an NSTrackingArea object by invoking the initWithRect:options:owner:userInfo: initializer with an option of NSTrackingCursorUpdate (along with any other desired options). Then add the created object to a view with addTrackingArea:. Thereafter, the entry of the mouse into the tracking area generates an NSCursorUpdate event; .. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html

Comment: Tried this, but cursorUpdate isn't getting called. Question updated to current code

Comment: Subclass NSView and add code there. Override updateTrackingAreas and add tracking areas there (remove existing and add new. Hold a strong pointer to it). The code has no place in viewcontroller and your tracking areas are discarded/wrong once you resize window/view. Do not disable cursor areas and then change cursor -> it will not get called. (this is the mistake)

Comment: Still can't seem to make it work. Could you please check the current code. Now the cursor image is not even changing!

Comment: @unkown your updateTrackingAreas  needs to have super. Remove and then add new tracking rect there. You are adding same adding trackingarea  without removing the one you previously created. Remove first the one you hold strong pointer and add a new one + store strong pointer. Try to add to tracking areaa mouseentered/exited and add corresponding methods to see if they are called

Comment: disableCursorRects works only for your own window. It cannot prevent other frontmost app from changing the cursor. https://gist.github.com/xhruso00/426b3e87870373b75f87823da6d88bea